# Passing Enum List to Criteria

Tags: grails, groovy, criteria

I have a domain Payment

```
class Payment {
  String name
  PaymentType paymentType
}
```

**PaymentType is an ENUM**

to search all payments of a particular payment type is simple

```
def results = Payment.createCriteria.list = {
  'in' ('paymentType', PaymentType.valueOf(params.paymentType))
}
```

how can i handle the situation when I want to search all Payments against more then one payment type i.e. if params.paymentType is an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If paymentType is an array, you can do something like this:

```
def results = Payment.createCriteria().list {
   'in' ('paymentType', params.paymentType.collect{PaymentType.valueOf(it)})
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ataylor for your prompt reply :)

Answer (score 0):

@ataylor:

I am not really sure.. but shouldnt it be

`def results = Payment.createCriteria().list {
   'in' ('paymentType',new params.paymentType.collect{PaymentType.valueOf(it)})
}`

or you'll be getting an error

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: params for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder`