# Grails select domain objects based on an enum value in an enum list property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm having trouble selecting items from a list of domain objects based on a value in an enum list.

My domain object looks like this:

```
class Truck {
  static hasMany = [ makes: Make ]  
}
```

where a Make looks like this:

```
enum Make {
  KENWORTH, MACK, VOLVO 
}
```

I'm not really sure how do something like Truck.findByMake(Make.MACK) to give me all of the Trucks that have this Make in their list of Makes.  That call gives me this error:

```
No property found for name [make] for class [class Truck]
```

Any ideas? Grails 1.2.2.

Comment: you has a typo in the query. try Truck.findByMakes(Make.MACK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's tricky and not supported by the dynamic finders. I also don't know how to do this with Criteria queries, but the HQL would be

```
def mackTrucks = Truck.executeQuery(
   'select t from Truck t left join t.makes make where make=:make',
   [make: Make.MACK])
```

Comment: Thanks Burt, that worked a treat.  Shame there's no pretty grails way of doing it.

Comment: Has there been any update to Grails since 2011 to support this in dynamic finders?

Answer (score 0):

You can make ist with criteria query the answer is [her in the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253019/passing-enum-list-to-criteria) but you have to customize it. Maybe like this:

```
Truck.createCriteria.list ={makes{eq('name', Make.MACK)}
}
```

I think each Enum has the attribute name.