# How do I check if a given list is a subset of a field value in GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm working on some sort of advanced search feature with variable fields. Some of the search fields are lists of some primitive(ish) objects (String, enums, etc.). I want to be able to retrieve records whose values are a subset of some given list.

To illustrate, say I have a `Book` class (assume the model is appropriate this way):

```
class Book {
    ...
    List authors = []
    ...
}
```

In addition say we have the following book records:

```
Book(title: 'Great Expectations of Tom Sawyer', authors: ['cdickens', 'mtwain'])
Book(title: 'Huckleberry Potter in Bleak House', authors: ['cdickens', 'mtwain', 'jrowling'])
Book(title: 'A Christmas Carol', authors: ['cdickens'])
```

Then, I'm given a list of author (names) `authorFilter = ['cdickens', 'mtwain']` to search for any collaborative works of `cdickens` and `mtwain`. How do I express this using GORM's `where` construct? Is it even possible to cover this using it?

Basically, what I want to do is:

```
Book.where {
    authorFilter.every { it in authors }
}
```

Comment: Why is this question down voted? I wish people would at least explain that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a simpler way of doing this other than doing HQL query. Taking hints from [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830797/404604), I figured out a solution to my problem.

To be clear, the `Book` should already have relation to many `String` using the `hasMany` construct:

```
class Book {
    ...
    static hasMany = [authors: String]
    ...
}
```

To fetch results:

```
def results = Product.executeQuery("select p from Products p join p.tags t where t in :tags", [tags: givenTags])
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has [come up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856121/grails-how-to-best-construct-a-hibernate-criteria-builder-to-search-hasmany). Unfortunately, where nor criteria queries have an `every()` equivalent. But there's a hack that may work for you. But first, I'll expand on your domain model.

### Domain model

```
class Book {
    String title

    static hasMany = [authors: Author]
    static belongsTo = Author
}

class Author {
    String name

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

### HQL query

Using the domain model described above, you can use the following HQL query.

```
def hql = """
SELECT b FROM Book AS b
INNER JOIN b.authors AS a
WHERE a.name in :authors
GROUP BY b
HAVING COUNT(b) = :count
"""

def books = Book.executeQuery(hql, [authors: authorFilter, count: authorFilter.size()])
```

### How it works.

You can read about how this query works in the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856121/grails-how-to-best-construct-a-hibernate-criteria-builder-to-search-hasmany) question I mentioned.

Comment: Like I said, let's assume the model is appropriate for my needs. My concern really is on the list of Strings, and other primitive-like objects.

Comment: This does not answer the original question, it would return result similar to gorm list.any {} or is same as using "in" / "inList" in criteria

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is any better than @EmmanuelRosa's answer but I have another approach using HQL and the `executeQuery` method.

Using the same domain model he's given in his answer, I use the `MEMBER OF` expression to restrict the results.

```
def authorFilter = [Author.get(1)]

def authorMemberOfRestriction = ""
def namedParameters = [:]

authorFilter.eachWithIndex{ aut, ind ->
    authorMemberOfRestriction += ":author${ind} MEMBER OF b.authors AND "
    namedParameters.put("author" + ind, aut)
}

namedParameters.put('count', authorFilter.size())

def hql = """
FROM Book b 
WHERE 
(
${authorMemberOfRestriction}
size(b.authors) = :count
)
"""

def books = Book.executeQuery(hql, namedParameters)
```

Mine is somewhat different in that the `authorFilter` is a collection of `Author` domain class instances; I found it to work much easier for the `MEMBER OF` expression and truthfully is more of a depiction of how the real data would be modeled.

You can see that I build the multiple `MEMBER OF` expressions with the `eachWithIndex`, using the index on both sides of the named parameters.  It's not exactly pretty but I don't believe there is a way around this and still use this approach.

I think @EmmanuelRosa's approach is probably the 'cleaner' option but the `MEMBER OF` approach makes more sense in my head as far as the logic is concerned.